# Import a python module from a different folder with another module import in it

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following file structure:

```
main.py
Core/
    object_storage.py
    setup_logger.py
```

main.py:

```
from Core import object_storage
#rest doesn't matter
```

object_storage.py:

```
from setup_logger import logger
#rest doesn't matter
```

setup_logger.py:

```
import logging
import sys
Log_Format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stdout, 
                    format = Log_Format, 
                    level = logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

When I run object_storage.py it works perfectly, but when I want to run main.py it gives me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup_logger'
```

I checked os.getcwd() and I think the issue is the working directory remains the root folder where I have main.py when I want to import setup_logger from Core/object_storage.py.

What is the way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python runs your file, it adds the file's directory to the `sys.path` (this is where Python looks the modules and packages).

I recommend that you always check the `sys.path` in these situations then you can easily find out why this error happens.

When you run `main.py` only it's directory is added to the `sys.path`. So you can find the `setup_logger` with `Core.setup_logger` (Python knows where to find `Core` directory. change the `object_storage.py` file to:

```py
from Core.setup_logger import logger
```

Up until now running `main.py` works perfectly but now another issue raises. This time if you run `object_storage.py` itself, you get the error which says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Core'
```

So in order to be able to run both `main.py` and `object_storage.py` directly, consider adding the path to the `main.py`'s directory (where the `Core` exists) to `object_storage.py` because this time that directory is not going to be added automatically:

```py
# object_storage.py

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'PATH TO WHERE Core EXIST')
```